# Continuous HTTP error 403.14 after uploading my website

Tags: .net, angular

Let me sketch the situation quickly. I have a .NET WebApi backend and an Angular Frontend. I built my Angular and transferred it to my API folder. When I run my project locally (pressing IIS express) everything works fine.

[image]

Now when I deploy my website to the FTP server of my webhost with Microsoft Visual Studio I get an error 403.14 when going to my URL. I've contacted them and their answer was very vague.

Translated their answer was this: "You have 2 WWWROOOT folders (which I've solved and didn't help out) from which 1 is full of .dll files, this is not necessary at all (these . dll files are made by Microsoft Visual Studio when publishing). There is also no index.html file in the main folder."

Is it just me or are they even less incompetent with webhosting than I am? The reason why I chose this webhost is because it's a project for my dad and he's kind of old-fashioned on the "Microsoft, Amazon, ..." he wanted a webhost which he could contact in his own native language.

What am I doing wrong here or is this webhost not up to it and should I change? If so I've looked into Azure, they have several packages but I don't know which one to choose. It's a simple frontend and backend which won't generate too much traffic.

Comment: Error 403: "The server understood the request, but is refusing to authorize it.", RFC 7231[1]  so it look like the Server where your files are save didn't authorize you to access. Think you maybe should verify your files rights in reading and writing.

Comment: I think you need to enable IIS feature which is called "**Directory browsing**"

Please follow https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942062/http-error-403-14-forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage or try compare your server settings with deployed server